# Как сделать метки (теги) как на этом сайте?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

Пhи добавлении темы есть поле метки, на этом сайте, вот хочу сделать такое-же, но не знаю как это правильно называется что бы найти и почитать.

Т.е. в двух словах, иметь ввозможность добавлять теги в поле input или textarea через запятую или просто выбирая из списка.

Буду признателен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется Chips [(materialize)](https://materializecss.com/chips.html), [(MUI)](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-chip/).